# Get current scroll position of FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have this code:

```
<FlatList
    ref={(x) => (this.flatList = x)}
    data={players}
    style={this.props.style}
/>
```

What I need is to save the current scroll position of the `FlatList` when the user e.g. navigates away.

So something like `this.flatList.getCurrentScrollPosition()`.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FlatList` inherits all of `ScrollView` props. Therefore you can use `onScroll`.

```
onScroll = (event) => {
  const scrollOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about something equivalent to `element.scrollTop` in HTML, which would just query the element for its current position. Having the `onScroll` event fire at every single scroll event is way beyond my needs.

Comment: You can use the `scrollEventThrottle` prop to limit the amount of times it's fired