# (React-Native) FlatList show special Card when scrolling X amount of times

Tags: react-native

Hey I have a FlatList with Cards Items. And I want to achieve this scenario.

Scenario:

When Scrolling for example through 5 items in the Flatlist I want to show a feedback card instead of an item Card

How Can this by Implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `renderItem` method, you can access the `index` of the current card.

My suggestion would be rendering the feedback card right after every 5th item card.

A rough example will look like this (Not tested yet)

```js
const SampleApp = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <ItemCard item={item} />
        {(index > 0 && index % 5 === 0) ? <FeedbackCard /> : null}
      </>
    );
  };

  return <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={renderItem} />;
};
```

Comment: this will include the first index also

Comment: Thank you, this seem like a valid solution

Comment: @Hassan Kandil Yes you are right, I forgot to handle that case, adding `index > 0` to the condition will do, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

You can try following - track `onScroll` event for `FlatList`, check if you passed enough offset for 5 Rows, compute target row position and insert feedback card there in `FlatList` data.

Comment: Is there a way to get the index without specifying an offset, since in my Items I have a variable length, Each card has different size from the other ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268636/get-current-scroll-position-of-flatlist